# Vector Bundles over Spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I would like to understand how to construct a vector bundle over the n sphere give a map of its equatorial $(n-1)$-sphere into the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. My thought is that one extends the map to a tubular neighborhood of the equator by projection then uses this as the coordinate transformation between the two hemispheres.

I would then like to compute the top Stiefel-Whitney number of this bundle.
There is a paper of Milnor that says the top Stiefel-Whitney number is not zero.

Comment: Trivialize it over the top half, trivialize it over the bottom half. These trivializations differ along the equator by a map to $GL_n\mathbb R$.

Comment: To help with searching, the operation @MikeMiller describes above is called the clutching construction.

Comment: The top Stiefel-Whitney number of an arbitrary bundle $E \to S^n$ is not necessarily nonzero. Take the trivial bundle, for example.

Comment: All Stiefel-Whitney classes of a trivial vector bundle over a sphere are zero.

Comment: If a vector bundle is a direct sum of a trivial real line bundle and another vector bundle, then its top Stiefel-Whitney class is zero.

Comment: Which paper of Milnor's are you talking about?

Comment: The top Stiefel-Whitney class of $S^n$ is zero.

Comment: Right.  I guess I was thinking of an example where the map into GL(n:R) comes from a  smooth multiplication on the n-1 sphere. I do not wish to assume already that these multiplications exist only in dimension 1 3 and 7.

Comment: @Mike Miller Thank you Mike.

Comment: @Mike Miller I think there is a theorem that the top Stiefel Whitney class of a vector bundle over a sphere can be non-zero only if the sphere is the circle, the 3 sphere, or the 7 sphere. The existence of a multiplication guarantees this and this was the crux of my question. Also if the n-1 sphere is paralleizabe, one gets another map into Gl(n:R) which I think determines a bundle of non-zero top Stiefel Whitney class.